Get percentage result from 2 columns with Union
I'm working on a query with SQL Server that has the results of sales and comparative sales per date period based on the different products sold.
The result of the query looks like this
Product:qty sold:qty sold last year
------------------------------------
123          10           100
456          50           10

I'm trying to add another column that would give me the percentage of the 2 last columns so in this example
it would give me 10 and 500
In my query I have this:
SELECT 
    tbl.Product,
    ROUND(SUM(tbl.Sale), 2) AS Sale,
    ROUND(SUM(tbl.Sale_comp), 2) AS Sale_Comp


The tbl is created from my query
FROM 
    (
        /** query sale**/
        SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... GROUP BY ...
        UNION
        /** query sale_com **/
        SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... GROUP BY ...
) tbl
GROUP BY tbl.product

My tbl.sale and tbl.sale_comp are 2 SELECT queries joined by an UNION so that they get all the products sold from all the orders in the system and I have a GROUP BY tbl.product so I see only the product and the qty sold based on a variable of date.
I tried:
ROUND(SUM(tbl.Sale * 100 / tbl.Sale_comp) ,2) AS Perc 

which returns a "Divide by zero" error encountered even if there is data in both. If I remove the '/ tbl.Sales_Comp' it returns the correct tbl.sale * 100 amount
(tbl.sale * 100 / tbl.Sale_comp) as Perc

tells me that tbl.sale and tbl.sale_comp is not in GROUP BY
If a add the 2 tbl in the GROUP BY I have the divide by zero error encountered.
This line will work if I have numbers on both
ROUND(ROUND(SUM(tbl.sale * 100), 2) / ROUND(SUM(tbl.sales_comp), 2),2) AS Perc

if 1 of the column has a 0, I get the divide by 0 error. I tried with the ISNULL() function placed at a couple of places but always getting divide by 0 error encountered
Not sure what I can do to make the divide work as the sum for each subquery works perfectly just need it to divide the 2 columnsyour text

first which database server are you using, further for a full [mre] this is to wage

Please clarify the relation between [qty sold] [qty sold last year] and [Sale] [Sale_comp]

Try:  ROUND(ROUND(SUM(tbl.sale * 100), 2) / ROUND(NullIf(SUM(tbl.sales_comp), 0), 2),2) AS Perc

Perfect thanks George, works like a charm!
